# How to get display value from Django Choices directly from the declared choice constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Lets say I defined a model class

```
from model_utils import Choices

class SomeModel(TimeStampedModel):

    food_choices = Choices(
        (1, "WATER", "Water"),
        (2, "BURGER", "Burger"),
        (3, "BIRYANI", "Biryani")
    )
    food = models.IntegerField(choices=food_choices, default=food_choices.WATER)
```

How do I get the display part while using the choices as a variable?

eg. SomeModel.food_choices.WATER gives me 1, how do I get the value/string "Water"?

I know if I create an instance, then I can fetch the display value using `.get_food_display()` for that instance, but I don’t want that I just want to use it directly from the constant created for `Choices`, ie `food_choices`.

Comment: You can use model method for that

Comment: I think you can achieve it in "Choices"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it after some tinkering.

In the `Choices` variable, we have tuples where the respective first value is the key, eg. 1,2,3.

```
food_choices = Choices(
    (1, "WATER", "Water"),
    (2, "BURGER", "Burger"),
    (3, "SALAD", "Salad")
)
```

We know `SomeModel.food_choices.WATER` gives `1`, ie the key.

Now to get `'Water'` directly from the declared `Choices` constant we can get it using the declared key for that tuple:

```
eg. 
SomeModel.food_choices[2] # returns 'Burger'
SomeModel.food_choices[0] # throws KeyError: 0
```

If we don’t want to figure out what index(or magic numbers) 0 or 2 is, then use:

```
SomeModel.food_choices[SomeModel.food_choices.WATER] # returns 'Water'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/glossary/#term-property

> Also known as “managed attributes”, and a feature of Python since
> version 2.2. This is a neat way to implement attributes whose usage
> resembles attribute access, but whose implementation uses method
> calls.

```
from model_utils import Choices

class SomeModel(TimeStampedModel):

    food_choices = Choices(
        (1, "WATER", "Water"),
        (2, "BURGER", "Burger"),
        (3, "BIRYANI", "Biryani")
    )
    food = models.IntegerField(choices=food_choices, default=food_choices.WATER)

    @property
    def food(self):
        return self.get_food_display()
```

Comment: I don’t want to call an instance method, for that I need to create an instance which I don’t think I need to do.

Comment: Also why would I overwrite actual `food` column value?